# My new laptop does not automatically turn on when I'm opening the lid but it does turn off when the lid is closed

Tags: windows-10

My new laptop (HP ENVYx360 Convertible 15) is running on Windows 10 and it does not automatically turn on when I'm opening the lid.

The settings of the lid open action are "Turn on the display" but it still does not turn on when I'm opening the lid.

However, it turns off when I close the lid.

Comment: Set the Lid Properties to Suspend, not Hibernate and not Hybrid Sleep.  Start, Settings, System, Power and Sleep, Advanced Power Settings

Comment: There is not "Suspend" option there. Only "Do nothing/Sleep/Hibernate/Shut down"

Comment: Ask HP Support what is going on, because it is a new machine.

Comment: Have you tried to update the BIOS and drivers? HP engineer provided some suggestions in this [link](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/When-close-and-open-the-lid-screen-remains-black/m-p/6313924#M159206). You can also refer to this [thread](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/laptop-screen-stays-black-after-opening-lid.394817/) to see if any help